Properly pack NuGet file with binary dependency
I am currently trying to create a package for communication with an embedded device. One of the features I would like the package to offer is the ability to flash the device (STM32). Therefore, I want to pack the STMCubeProgrammer CLI into the NuGet package and have it unpacked into the output directory (as a deploy\ subdirectory) of projects consuming the package.
However, after hours of trying, pushing to my NuGet feed and restoring in consuming projects, I was not able to get this to work.
The files I need seem to be packed correctly into content/ of the NuGet package (I checked with both dotPeek and by opening the .nupkg as a zip file), however they are not copied to consumer's output directory on Build.
This is the .nuspec file of the package:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyLibraryProject</id>

    <!-- Metadata omitted for brevity -->

    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net7.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
    <!-- This is where the programmer files are. 'buildAction=Content' breaks (see below). -->
      <files include="deploy\**\*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\net7.0\MyLibraryProject.dll" target="lib\net7.0\MyLibraryProject.dll" />

    <file src="deploy\**\*.*" target="content\deploy" />

    <!-- This will fail, as contentFiles seem to be assumed to be text files and not binary files. -->
    <!-- <file src="deploy\**\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any\deploy" /> -->
  </files>
</package>

This may be the relevant part of the NuGet package's .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <!-- omitted for brevity -->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <NuspecFile>MyLibraryProject.nuspec</NuspecFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="deploy\**" Pack="true" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And, last but hardly least, here is the PackageReference in the consumer:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <!-- omitted for brevity -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- other package references omitted for brevity -->
    <PackageReference Include="MyLibraryProject" Version="0.1.0" GeneratePathProperty="true">
      <!-- Does not work: <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets> -->
      <!-- Does not work: <ExcludeAssets>none</ExcludeAssets> -->
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

As you can see, I tried using contentFiles (as described, e.g., here but that does not work) GeneratePathAttribute (which was described in an issue on GitHub) and tried to have IncludeAssets="All", as well as, ExcludeAssets=None.
TL;DR: I want to pack a deploy\ folder in a NuGet package and have it unpacked into consuming projects as <MyConsumer>\bin\Release\net7.0\deploy\.
